# for loop en una carpeta de mi PC javascript

Tags: javascript, illustrator

Actualmente me encuentro bsucando información para un script de Illustrator y necesito saber cómo plantear un for loop dentro de una carpeta en mi computador. En after effects lo que hago es crear una linea simple

```
for(var i = 1; i<=app.project.numItems;i++){
    var curItem = app.project.item(i);
}
```

de esta forma busco algo entre los items de mi projecto. ahora mi pregunta es, ¿cómo podría hacer eso mismo en una carpeta dentro de mi computadora? Por ejemplo en la carpeta documentos. Entiendo que la ruta sería algo como C:\Users\temp2.documentos

Comment: Javascript no tiene las capacidades de acceder al sistema de archivos de una computadora.

Comment: uhh eso no lo sabía... igualmente me parece que dentro de ExtendScript de Adobe si se puede para poder acceder a documentos , importar y abrir archivos y proyectos. Me imagino que tendría que ir a esa fuente y ver cómo enfrentar el código. Muchas gracias igual. Está bueno saber que esa es una limitante dentro del lenguaje. Saludos!

Comment: Posible duplicado de [¿Qué puedo hacer para traer imágenes desde cualquier carpeta externa y poder mostrarlas?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/76356/qu%c3%a9-puedo-hacer-para-traer-im%c3%a1genes-desde-cualquier-carpeta-externa-y-poder-mos)

Comment: Se me ocurre quizás crear un array con los diferentes objetos (en este caso los proyectos de illustrator o after effects) y luego hacer un loop dentro de ese array e ir aplicando lo que necesito. Averigué que dentro de ExtendScript se puede abrir un proyecto con el siguiente método:

Comment: @Lixus, directamente en el navegador no lo permite, pero usando `nodejs` tienes el módulo `fs` que si lo permite

Comment: Mmm ya eso excede mis conocimientos. Gracias igual!